Kohler Avec tub drain help
This tub (Kohler Avec 25833-RA-0) has an integral overflow drain, meaning the tub is designed like a sink and only has one drain connection (vs your typical drain and overflow connections). That said, there is a rubber gasket that must be pressed into the underside of the tub drain hole and is kept in place by a locknut that threads onto the drain and is sealed with silicone. The screws of this locknut protrude enough so that the drain shoe does not fully thread into place.
I can get about 2-4 threads of the drain seated into the drain shoe before the locknut screws stop me from further tightening.
Once installed and tested, there is a very small leak coming from the metal drain threads and ABS drain shoe. I now have the facepalm realization that I did not use a thread sealant at this connection. I plan to disassemble and add the sealant, but can’t help but think that the lock nut screws are also part of the problem.
My first thought is to cut the excess threads of the locknut screws to create more room for the drain to screw into the shoe, but doing so would be very tricky due to it being an awkward space to work in via my access panel in the closet. Cutting these screws would also remove my ability to adjust them should that be needed in the future.
Any recommendations on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Will the simple addition of thread sealant fix my issue? Or do I also need the drain to seat further into the shoe.
The toe-tap drain, rubber gasket, and locknut all came with the tub. My ABS tub shoe is from Home Depot and is standard size.


No plumbing is "sealed with silicone". The rubber gasket does that. Caulk has no place in plumbing. Save it for fixture mounting.

4 threads would probably be enough. 2 wouldn't, in my opinion. Which is more accurate?

Sounds like you simply need a thicker gasket or a round shim.

The drain Kohler recommends for its Avec alcove series is for a stand alone tub.  These two different tubs simply have different size drain specs - review for yourself or call kohler tech.  Let’s don’t forget about the specs of Kohler Avec alcove soaker tub w integral overflow. It states this tub is delivered w a pre-installed drain - it’s not.  After setting and pulling several times I realized kohler spoofed. Hey we all make mistakes.  I found a drain made by westbrass that will fit this tub and seal.  Google tub drain for alcove tub w integrated overflow.  Good luck all you plumbers out there!!

That tub drain is clearly not designed for use with a standard "drain shoe", which seals by means of a rubber gasket against the bottom of the tub. You have presumably standard 1 1/2" male pipe threads to connect to at the drain, so find an 1 1/2" female-threaded adapter and go from there. Thread sealant is used only when connecting tapered pipe joints, never where gaskets, ferrules, or other sealing means are used.
